# How to unserialize JSON data in Express/Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express

So I have on the client side within a controller:

```
 $scope.authenticate = function() {
            var creds = JSON.stringify({email: this.email, password: this.password});
            $http.post('/authenticate', creds).
                success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                   // etc
                }).
                error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                  // etc
                });
        };
```

And on the server side:

```
app.post('/authenticate', function(req, res) {
    console.log("Unserialized request: " + JSON.parse(req));
});
```

But I'm getting an error when I try to parse the request. I can't figure out why. Any ideas?

Comment: You probably don't want to parse the request object itself. You want to parse a field with in the body (req.body or req.body.whatever)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the express.bodyParser middleware which will do the parsing for you and give you `req.body` as an object ready to go.

```
var express = require('express');

app.post('/authenticate', express.bodyParser(), function(req, res) {
    console.log("Unserialized request: " + req.body);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

To complete Peter Lyons' answer, I think you can use express.bodyParser(), but it's better if you use

```
[express.urlencoded(), express.json()]
```

in place of

```
express.bodyParser()
```

i.e.

```
app.post('/authenticate', [express.urlencoded(), express.json()], function(req, res) {
console.log("request body= " + req.body);
});
```

It also takes care of parsing the request. But, it's more secure and since you only need json and not any file. If you use bodyParser any one can send file as well, to your post request.

Comment: Have read several questions about this and this is the only solution that works with the new version. Thanks!